# Modify the username sign in custom policy to also accept email login

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I need users to have unique usernames for my site, so I am using the sample policy here: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-signup-or-signin/policy
to do that. However, this sign in does not allow the users to later sign in with the email that they signed up with. Using the default email sign somehow does not work with accounts created with this, I suppose because it stores email where the policy I am using stores username. How can I make users able to log in with the email they put when signing up in addition to the username.

I would greatly appreciate some plug and play code if possible (minus the client id and other private info, of course. Please don't accidentally post that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sample only allows usernames as you point out.

You need this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-or-email) that allows both.

**Update**

To log in with both, you need to link identities.

e.g. create the user with this:

```
"identities": [
  {
    "signInType": "userName",
    "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
    "issuerAssignedId": "johnsmith"
  },
  {
    "signInType": "emailAddress",
    "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
    "issuerAssignedId": "jsmith@yahoo.com"
  }  
]
```

Comment: This sample is very close, though the OR seems to be very potent. If you sign up with username, you can not log in using your email in the future, still leaving the issue that if you sign up with a username then forget it you are somewhat stuck. 
I searched for a sign in with email sample that enforces unique display names but could not find one, does this exist? That would be a simpler solution to my problem, I think

Comment: No - display name does not have to be unique. B2C enforces uniqueness across identities e.g. email, username, phone number

Comment: Sorry for not understanding, but where would I put/what do I do with the code you added in the edit?

Comment: None of the files appear to have anything called "identities"

Comment: You could do this when you create the user. How are the users created?

Comment: After everything thats happened today, I just saw that apparently we arent supposed to even be using b2c anymore and instead are supposed to be using the new thing, so delete the directory I was working in... so thanks for the help, but I dont need it anymore

Comment: The answer didnt give me what I wanted but since it gave me what I asked I marked it correct